# WeasyPrint: fixed footer tag overlapped by long table on each pdf page

Tags: python, css, pdf, formatting, weasyprint

I generate with Django a *table* that I render in pdf thanks to WeasyPrint.

This table is potentially really long (rows number speaking) and so potentially ends in several pages pdf results. I must include a static footer at each end of page so I applied css *fixed* rule.

My problem is this footer is overlapped by the very long table. How can I ask to WeasyPrint (through css I think) to break the table before each footer and continue to render the table on the next page ?

```
<table>
    <tr></tr> <!-- a lot of rows, potentially spreading on several A4 pages -->
</table>

<footer style="position: fixed"> <!-- footer contents will be repeated and overlapped on each page until </table> is not reached -->

</footer>
```

*I tried to use css rules as padding-bottom applied on table tag but with no success*

thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: If I remember well I used a very ugly empirical solution. I noticed that each page of the rendered pdf can display arount 40 lines (lines of my table was consistant, at least). With Django template engine I could used for loop like ( in pseudo code) : for line in lines 
render line
if forloop.counter == 40
  close the table (</table>) and <br> any time you need to make space to the fixed footer
  reopen a table
endif
endfor

Comment: sorry for the formatting and the fuzzy answer, I do not have the code anymore and I quit this project more 6 months ago. Nevertheless, did you get my idea ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking about doing before, but after some research I'm going to just use wkhtmltopdf because it supports `page-break-inner: avoid`. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, and I will take a look on wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a solution for it.

First of all you've to define your page margins:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 15mm 20mm;
}
```

I've a top & bottom margin of 15mm.

When you now place a fixed footer in the page/body, it will be "inside" these margins and non-`fixed` elements will overlap it. So what you want to do is moving the fixed footer "outside" of these margins:

```
footer
{
    position        : fixed;
    right           : 0;
    bottom          : 0;
    margin-bottom   : -10mm;
    height          : 10mm;
    text-align      : right;
    font-size       : 10px;
}
```

The `fixed` and `bottom` properties will place your footer on every page on the bottom, but within the defined margins (where it is overlapped). The `height` specifies the footer height, which is then moved "outside" the margins by the negative `margin-bottom` property. Just make sure that `margin-bottom` >=  `height`.

Cheers
Domi